# Flutter upgrade to 3.19.3 material/elevated_button.dart Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match

Tags: flutter, dart

- After upgrading to the '3.19.3' (latest version) of Flutter for my
  web application, I encountered errors that were not present before
  the upgrade. Initially, I faced 2 issues:  First I got these 3
  errors.

1 -> `Error: The type 'JSObject' can't be used as supertype.`

2 -> `../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart:151:22: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.`
static ButtonStyle styleFrom({

- To address the first issue, I included 'web: ^0.5.0' in my
  'pubspec.yaml' file, which resolved the problem with 'JSObject'.
- But, I am still facing other unresolved error. However, I have never
  used elevated button for my project.
- I tried to solve the second problem by following these steps: First I
  ran this command

> flutter clean

then I added the latest version to my pubspec.yaml file

> flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1

then I ran the the following command.

> flutter pub get

However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With the flutter 3.19 update, `styleFrom` [has been removed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/139267).

Check your installed packages or try to upgrade with `flutter pub upgrade`.